# createInstance vs createInstanceWithArguments

Tags: typescript, libreoffice, uno

I am trying to [generate Typescript definitions from the LibreOffice IDL](https://github.com/zspitz/ts-activex-gen#generating-a-tsnamespace-for-the-libreoffice-api) (via Doxygen-generated XML).

The [XMultiServiceFactory interface](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1lang_1_1XMultiServiceFactory.html) has two methods for creating instances: `createInstance` and `createInstanceWithArguments`. However, I can't seem to find which types require arguments and what they are, and should be instantiated with `createInstanceWithArguments`; and which types don't require arguments, and should be instantiated with `createInstance`.

Being able to define overloads based on the string parameter passed to the method would enable static typing based on those overloads:

```
// automatically typed as com.sun.star.frame.Desktop
let desktop = objServiceManager.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
```

otherwise the result would have to be explicitly typed:

```
let desktop = objServiceManager.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop')
    as com.sun.star.frame.Desktop;
```

**How can I know from the documentation whether a given type needs arguments or not, and what those arguments are?**

(LibreOffice 5.3.5 / Windows 10 64-bit)

(Originally posted at [ask.libreoffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/127593/createinstance-vs-createinstancewitharguments/), with no answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Service Manager dev guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Service_Manager):

> The service definition should describe the meaning of each element.

I take this to mean that the IDL files should tell what if any arguments are needed.  For example, in the source code file  `/offapi/com/sun/star/configuration/ConfigurationProvider.idl`, there is a detailed description of arguments, and the comments state that it is also possible to create an instance without any arguments.  (The code does not show the arguments however; it's explained only in comments).

It looks like all the relevant information from that file has been included in the online documentation for [ConfigurationProvider](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/configuration/ConfigurationProvider.html), so there is no need to actually look at the IDL files.

Contrast that with [com.sun.star.frame.Desktop](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/Desktop.html), which does not take arguments, as shown in the example at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Using_the_Desktop.